# carrierwave: update active record column within uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, uploader

I'm using Carrierwave to upload video files to my Rails app.  My Video model has an attribute "rotation" which I'm using to store the orientation of the video (e.g., 90, 180, 270, etc.).

I want to set the value of "rotation" within my Uploader, where I'm determining whether the video is rotated or not:

```
require 'mini_exiftool'

class VideoPathUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

process :encode

def encode
    video = MiniExiftool.new(@file.path)
    orientation = video.rotation

    # save the orientation of the video record here ??
    if orientation == 90
      # rotate video
      Rails.logger.debug "portrait video"
      aspect_ratio = video.imageheight.to_f / video.imagewidth.to_f
      encode_video(:mp4, custom: "-vf transpose=1", aspect: aspect_ratio)
    else
      aspect_ratio = video.imagewidth.to_f / video.imageheight.to_f
      encode_video(:mp4, resolution: :same, aspect: aspect_ratio)
    end
    instance_variable_set(:@content_type, "video/mp4")
    :set_content_type_mp4
  end
```

**How do I reference the model and update one of its attributes within my uploader?**

Answer (score 0):

to reference the video record within my uploader, I just had to call modeL:

orientation = video.rotation
model.rotation = orientation